# check a host is accepting https conection

Tags: http, https

How to check a host is accepting https connections or not? Since i don't have the permission to access the host. Is there any tools/utilities, which checks the machine is accepting https connection or not?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is OpenSSL's [`s_client`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:S_client(1)). This would look something like this:

```shell
$ openssl s_client -connect host:443
```

The next best thing were to try with [netcat](https://nmap.org/ncat/):

```shell
$ nc --ssl host 443
```

In both cases, you will have to send a HTTP request "by foot." If you successfully establish a connection to the given host, you will have only shown that something SSL-ish is listening on that port. In the case of netcat, it will look something like this:

```shell
$ nc -v --ssl host 443 <<EOD
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: host
Connection: close

EOD
```

Another option were [cURL](https://curl.haxx.de), if you do not wish to deal with the messy details of HTTP:

```shell
$ curl --http1.1 --tlsv1 -Iv https://host
```